# Can I use a USB keyboard and mouse with the Nexus 7?

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Can I use my usb keyboard and mouse while running Ubuntu on the Nexus 7?  The interface is not quite ready for touch input, and I'd like to be able to help test.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, many (if not all) usb devices will be supported by using an OTG (on the go) USB cable.  Using this cable, you can attach a USB hub to the Nexus 7, and attach a mouse and keyboard to that.  This has been testing and verified as being fully functional.

Comment: Yippee :) that is really good news.might now have to buy otg cable